# Home loan application factors for self-employed

Tags: loans, self-employment, home-loan

What factors are considered in applying for a home loan where the primary income of our household is from self-employment?

Details:

- Salaried, W-2 employee of an S-Corp (50% owned)
- Corporation is about 6 months old

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any earning history before this? That history will probably be part of the bank's request, to confirm a track record of earning power. 
I've gone through multiple refinances, each time the bank requests prior two years' W2s for my wife and me, along with a recent pay stub. I'd view a six month old company as risky, but of course, not everyone working for young companies are stuck unable to get a mortgage, you'd have a credit report and other work history.

Comment: Don't forget a big down payment. The more skin you have in the game, the more likely a bank is to overlook potential risk factors.

Comment: d'oh! - Absolutely - a large enough down payment will get a valid "no-income" type mortgage. Not to be confused with liar loans, the low or no doc are legitimate products with a large enough downpayment. Thanks, duff, great point.

Comment: Yeah basically all that history is for people with no capital. Given the risk models that recognizes most people live paycheck to paycheck. If you have an account with a lot of money in it, and can show the probability of future earnings, then the bank won't care about all the other policies they have the peons jump through.

Comment: Is "earning power" just based on total annual income on your tax return? or total W-2 income? or something else?

Comment: I use it to mean a track record of some sort. There's a difference in making $100K/yr at a 6 month old startup with no history vs a history of similar income at say 3 companies over the last 6 years.